# How can I access the scheme in the http header with a HAproxy acl?

Tags: websocket, http-headers, load-balancing, acl, haproxy

I don't just want to access the URL or the domain on my load balancer with HAproxy, but also the protocol (http, https, ws...) How can I do this for websocket scheme?

```
acl ws_wfe01 hdr(host) -I example.de
acl ws_wfe02 hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket 
acl ws_wfe03 hdr_beg(host) -i ws
```

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine and I found a workable solution:

```
acl hdr_connection_upgrade hdr(Connection)  -i upgrade
acl hdr_upgrade_websocket  hdr(Upgrade)     -i websocket
```